# Alternate entry point

Tags: glsl

I am writing a glsl shader (`#version 450`) and want an alternative entry point. Now when compiling with

```
glslangValidator -V foo.comp -e Test
```

it complains, about `void main()` not being found. I am wondering why it seems to be ignoring the `-e` option.

Comment: Afair you need to compile with the SPIR-V tools instead of the glslangvalidator if you want to use an alternate entry point.

Comment: TBH `-e` and `--sep` behave like they are completely ignored. Possibly not implemented?